# How to get index of the first not null array element?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any nice way to get the index of the first not null String array element? Yes, you can write

```
int index;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i] != null) {
       index = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

but maybe there is possible to do it in a more beautiful manner? For example, you can use `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull` method to get the first not null element of the array, maybe there's something similar to obtain index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One trick is to create a stream of indexes, and then find the first one that points to a non-null value:

```
int index =
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
             .filter(i -> arr[i] != null)
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(-1 /* Or some other default */);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Java 9` there is a method called `takeWhile()`. you can use it in your array of numbers like so.

```
long index = Arrays.stream(yourArray).takeWhile(Objects::isNull).count();
```

**Edit**

In case there are no non-null elements index will be equal to the length of the array.

You can make a check for it.

```
if(index == array.length) {
    index = -1;
}
```

Comment: But this might behave unexpectedly if there is _no_ non-null element...

Comment: @tobias_k , hmm you are right, if there are no  non-null elements it will return the length of the array. Thanks for remark. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

For example, like that in Java version earlier than 8:

```
static final Object ANY_NOT_NULL = new Object()
{
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        return obj != null;
    }
};

public static int firstIndexOfNotNull(Object... values)
{
    return Arrays.asList(values).indexOf(ANY_NOT_NULL);
}
```

Comment: This breaks the assumption of `equals`' commutative nature. It will work if `Arrays.asList` happens to call equals on the object you pass to `indexOf` (as OpenJDK 8 seems to do), but it's perfectly OK for the JDK to implement it the other way round, in which case your solution will not work

Comment: Javadoc comment on `indexOf` clearly says that:
`Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.`.

Answer (score 0):

Object[] dizi = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, 8, 9, 10 };

```
    Object t = null;
    int len = dizi.length;
    System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, len).filter(i -> t == dizi[i]).findFirst().orElse(-1)); // can't find.);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int last = list.size() - 1;
for (; last >= 0 && list.get(last) == null; last--) { /* no-op */ }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.